# xamarin portable library and Json.net

Tags: json.net, xamarin

I am not able to use Json.net in the portable library. I set the portable library to use profile 4.5 -78. It compile fine but during runtime, it throws file not found exception. Any body encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nuget is probably adding a reference to the `portable-net45+wp80+win8` portable assembly for Json.NET, which is incompatible with the current versions of Xamarin. To get things working you can manually switch the reference to use `portable-net40+sl4+wp7+win8`

[image: Switching to compatible portable Json.NET reference]

Comment: @Greg This solved it for me too, but I had to add the reference to the ios project in addition to my PCL library. Did you have the same experience?

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue with the newer Nuget package (`Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.1`). To solve the problem, I had to replace the `HintPath` in the PCL csproj with `portable-net40+sl5+wp80+win8+monotouch+monoandroid`.

For that, edit manually the csproj file, and locate this section:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=...">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.1\lib\portable-net45+wp80+win8\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

and adapt the path to the DLL.

Comment: this is the correct answer. more on this issue here: github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/pull/235